# Can moderators see private messages on a XenForo forum?

Tags: xenforo

Are all private messages visible to forum moderators?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, only the participants can see the discussion [according to a Xenforo staff member](https://xenforo.com/community/threads/can-moderators-see-private-messages.124383/).
Note that anyone with database access can see the messages.

There also are Xenforo add-ons (for administrators) [for tracking private messages](https://xenforo.com/community/threads/can-moderators-see-private-messages.124383/#post-1121353):

> - https://xenforo.com/community/resources/conversation-monitor.4131/
> - https://xenforo.com/community/resources/monitor-personal-conversations.5050/
> - https://xenforo.com/community/resources/read-conversations-enhanced-themescorp-com.4754/
> - https://xenforo.com/community/resources/conversation-monitor.4131/
> - https://xenforo.com/community/resources/th-conversations-access-by-themehouse.2357/